# Does Restlet support batch processing?

Tags: java, android, odata, restlet

Does Restlet's [OData extension](http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_2.0/13-restlet/28-restlet/287-restlet.html) support [batch processing](http://www.odata.org/developers/protocols/batch)?  The [service class](http://www.restlet.org/documentation/2.0/jse/ext/org/restlet/ext/odata/Service.html) only has updateEntity and addEntity (note: singular) methods.

Answer (score 0):

No, currently the OData module does not support batching

https://github.com/restlet/restlet-framework-java/issues/925